# Gitlab Runner cannot retrieve dependency repo in a Powershell executor

Tags: powershell, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

### CI Runner Context

- Gitlab version : 13.12.2 (private server)
- Gitlab Runner version : 14.9.1
- Executor : shell executor (PowerShell)
- Exploitation system : Windows 10
- Project in Python (may be unrelated)
- (using Poetry for dependency management)

### The Problem

I am setting up an automated integration system for a project that has several internal dependencies that are hosted on the same server as the project being integrated. If I run the CI with a `poetry update` in the yml file, the Job console sends an **exit with error code 128** upon calling a git clone on my internal dependency.

To isolate the problem, I tried simply calling a `git clone` on that same repo. The response is that the runner cannot authenticate itself to the Gitlab server.

#### What I Have Tried

Reading through the Gitlab docs, I found that the runners need authorization to pull any private dependencies. For that, Gitlab has created [deploy keys](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_keys/).

So I followed the instructions to create the deploy key for the dependency and added it to the sub-project's deploy key list. I then ran into the exact same permissions problem.

What am I missing?

(For anyone looking for this case for a Winodws PowerShell, the user that the runner uses is *nt authority/system*, a system only user that I have not found a way to access as a human. I had to make the CI runner do the ssh key creation steps.)

Example *.gitlab-ci.yml* file:

```
#Commands in PowerShell

but_first:
  #The initial stage, always happens first
  stage: .pre
  script:
    # Start ssh agent for deploy keys
    - Start-Service ssh-agent
    # Check if ssh-agent is running
    - Get-Service ssh-agent
    - git clone ssh://git@PRIVATE_REPO/software/dependency-project.git
```

Comment: Have you tried [using the builtin CICD token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ci_job_token.html) with HTTPS auth? `git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.example.com/<namespace>/<project>`

Comment: You may need to use `${env:CI_JOB_TOKEN}` for [accessing variables in powershell](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#use-variables-with-powershell). So keep that in mind when viewing examples in the docs.

Comment: @sytech Thanks! I did try your solution, but now I get a : error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number. I am using a self-managed gitlab instance, so I might be running into a known bug that gitlab warns about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem of pulling internal dependencies via *completely bypassing* the ssh pull of the source code and by *switching from poetry to hatch* for dependency management (I'll explain why further down).

## Hosting the compiled dependencies

For this, I compiled my dependency project's source code into a distribution-ready package (in this context it was a python wheel).
Then used Gitlab's Packages and Registries offering to host my package. Instead of having packages in each source code project, I pushed the packages of all my dependencies to a project I created for this single purpose.

My .gitlab-ci.yaml file looks like this when publishing to that project:

```
deploy:
# Could be used to build the code into an installer
  stage: Deploy
  script:
    - echo "deploying"
    - hatch version micro
    # only wheel is built (without target, both wheel and sdist are built)
    - hatch build -t wheel
    - echo "Build done ..."
    - hatch publish --repo http://<private gitlab repo>/api/v4/projects/<project number>/packages/pypi --user gitlab-ci-token --auth $CI_JOB_TOKEN
    - echo "Publishing done!"
```

## Pulling those hosted dependencies (& why I ditched poetry)

My first problem was having pip find the extra pypi repository with all my packages. But pip already has a solution for that!

In it's pip.ini file(to find where it is, you can do *pip config -v list*), 2 entries need to be added:

```
[global]
extra-index-url = http://__token__:<your api token>@<private gitlab repo>/api/v4/projects/<project number>/packages/pypi/simple

[install]
trusted-host = <private gitlab repo>
```

This makes it functionally the same as adding the *--extra-index-url* and *--trusted-host* tags while calling pip install.

Since I was using a dependency manager, I was not directly using pip, but the manager's wrapper for pip. And here comes the main reason why I decided to change dependency managers: poetry does not read or recognize pip.ini. So any changes done in any of those files will be ignored.

With the configuration of the pip.ini file, any dependencies I have in the private package repo will also be searched for the installation of projects. So the line:

```
- git clone ssh://git@PRIVATE_REPO/software/dependency-project.git
```

changes to a simple line:

```
- pip install dependency-project
```

Or a line in pyproject.toml:

dependencies = [

"dependency-project",

"second_project",

]